# is there a way to make a flutter switch button keep printing until the button is clicked again(disabeled)

Tags: flutter, while-loop, flutter-layout, toggle, sensors

I am using a flutter switch plugin to enable (toggle on) for my app to keep performing a task until the switch is disabled.
But I am stuck trying to implement a function for that.

below is my function to perform the task. But it is not working, (even though it starts working, I can't stop it.

```
>    onToggle: (value) {
>           setState(() {
>           isRecording = value;
>           });
>                 while (value ==true){
>                 print("data is been recorded");
>                 
>                 }
> 
>           },

I would really appreciate any suggestion or help with this problem. thanks in advance
```

Comment: Why you use while loop instead of if?

Comment: @Wai Han Ko ; I use while loop cuz I want it to continuously print until the button is disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace performTask() method instead of while loop

```
void performTask() {
 Timer.periodic(
   const Duration(seconds: 1),
   (Timer t) => {
     isRecording == true ? print("Working Task") : t.cancel(),
   },
 );
}


----------

 onToggle: (value) {
        setState(() {
        isRecording = value;
        });
              performTask();

        },
```

Comment: Thank you very very much.
This works for me. I really appreciate it

Comment: You are very very welcome!